# Is a vector space a subset of an abelian group?

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups

As we know that given a vector space $E$, we can remove the scalar multiplication operator, then the elements of $E$ forms a group and commute with each others (we refer this commutative group to abelian group).

I am not 100% sure that if a vector space $E$ is a subset of the abelian group? Could anyone give me an answer and explanation please? Thanks in advance!

Comment: yes, first 4 conditions is abelian group

Comment: The word "subset" is misleading. If $V$ is a vector space, then $(V,+)$ is an abelian group. So it is $V$ itself (which is a subset of $V$, but ...).

Comment: Thanks@DietrichBurde. Would you mind explaining more detail about "So it is $V$ itself, which is a subset of $V$" please? Did you mean that given a vector space $V$, the abelian group $(V, +)$ of the vector space $V$ is a subset of $V$?

Comment: Yes, every set is a subset of itself.

Comment: Thank you @DavidWheeler. Actually, I am confused now. Regarding the vector space $V$, what's the relationship between $V$ and its abelian group $(V, +)$? I thought $(V,+)$ is a larger set than vector space $(V, \mathbb{F}, +, \cdot)$.

Comment: We say for any set $V$ that $V$ is a subset of $V$.  But we would not say that $(V,+,\cdot)$ is a *subset* of $(V,+)$.  Is that the question?

Comment: Thanks @GEdgar. I understand now.

Answer (score 1):

A vector space is composed of 4 things, a set $V$, a field $\Bbb F$, an operation $+$ and a scalar multiplication $\cdot$, written as $(V,\Bbb F,+,\cdot)$ here. It satisfies the following axioms

1. $+$ is closed
2. $+$ is commutative
3. $+$ has inverses
4. $+$ has an identity element
5. $\cdot$ is a function from $\Bbb F\times V$ to $V$
6. $\cdot$ is distributive over $+$
7. $\cdot$ has an identity
8. $\cdot$ is associative

The first 4 axioms means that $(V,+)$ is an abelian group, but notice that it's the same set, $V$ that we are using both for the abelian group and the vector space. The vector space adds a field which gives scalar multiplication that results in another element in $V$ and not in something else.